# Angular Material table column

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I get in a table made in Angular material the index of a clicked column?

I use
`<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true; let i = index;"     (click)="clickEventT(i)"></tr>`

but something missing.

Comment: Do you want to get index of column, when clicked on particular column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<tr ...></tr>` tag is actually the header row and not the header cell.
Now the index of each header cell within the table depends on the `displayedColumns` ordering, depending on the use case it might be dynamically changing or not. An hardcoded solution could be perfectly valid as in many cases re-ordering columns wont happen.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="showIndex('weight')"> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="showIndex('weight')"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- ... -->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

In scenarios where the displayed columns change
The `showIndex(columnName: string)` function can display/return the column index as follows

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['weight','...'];
showIndex(columnName: string): void {
   const index = this.displayedColumns.indexOf(columnName);
   console.log(index);
   alert(index);
}
```